# The closure of a subspace is itself a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

[image]

---

> How can we get the boxed result from the previous line?  That line tells us that $ x_n + y_n$ converges to some point  $x+y$ that may or may not belong to $A$, so how do we know from this that  $x+y$ belongs to the closure of $A$? What result/definition are we using? thanks

Comment: This is a misprint. $x+y $ is in closure of $A$ not $A$

Comment: @JoJomax Okay, but why? Why is it in the closure of A? please

Comment: $x_n +y_n \in \overline{A}$ for all $n$. So $\lim (x_n+y_n) \in \overline{A}$

Comment: @JoJomax Is this a consequence of the fact that the closure of $A$ is a closed set?

Comment: Yes. Because closure of A is closed

Comment: If "closure" were defined in its most general form then this would be trivial. The closure of a set $A$ in a topological space $X$ is the intersection of all closed sets in  $X$ that contain $A$. This clearly is an idempotent operation, and so we are done. Much simpler, easier to understand, and less work than mucking about with  limits of sequences (which need not even be unique in arbitrary topological spaces).